# Simple examples of a webpage serving video to mobile?

Tags: video, mobile, mp4, transcoding

I've been trying to get some straightforward example of a page with a few video types on it that work in iPhone android winmo and blackberry.

I spent a lot of time transcoding today but outside of iPhone I just keep hitting obstacles.

Anyone know of some simple example?

So you know I tried
I load an mp4 and 3gp video up and sent links of the videos to the phones. The phone either tries to download it or just doesn't play.

I'm using encoding.com for the transcode.

And I plan to use amazon s3 for the host.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You very well may be better off starting with an existing open source player, like [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/).  It is going to resolve a lot of issue for you.  **That said, your problem is probably not the player.**

Pay close attention the **the encoding of the video**.  Just because your media is MPEG-4 h.264 does not mean it will play on a give device--they all have their own particular restrictions.  Video CODEC, resolution, audio CODEC, bit rate, etc.

- [Blackberry media type restrictions](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/subcategories/?userType=1&category=Media%20Types%20Supported%20on%20BlackBerry%20Smartphones)
- [iPhone encoding guide](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/the-complete-guide-to-ipod-video-formats-and-display-resolutions/)

If the phones are downloading the file, then you may have a MIME type issue.  If it is just not playing, then it is likely to be encoding related.